# Redirect to the same page user was in before SAML token Expires in Spring Security

Tags: spring, redirect, spring-saml

I have developed a Spring security SAML based SSO application.I wanted to redirect the user to the page he is using before the saml token expires.After refreshing the page it is redirecting to home page.i have used HttpSessionRequestCache, but it does not have any value after it reaches the LoginSuccessHandler.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: code base is similiar to below blog .but if saml token expires and session is still active my app single sign in process will happen and reidrect to home page.if the user is working in different page at that point of time he will be redirected to home page after sign in.                                      
   https://dzone.com/articles/diving-into-sso-with-spring-saml-and-ssocircle-pit